# image rotation /animation

Tags: java

I need a java method to rotate an image like [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/76/Wheel_of_Fortune_template.svg/513px-Wheel_of_Fortune_template.svg.png), I would like to have some kind of animation like the real "wheel of fortune" Do you have any suggestions?

P.S. If it is possible to rotate that image how can I handle the values?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out - should get you started.

[Java Rotate Image 45 degrees](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/RotateImage45Degrees.htm)

Answer (score 1):

The [Animated Icon](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/21/animated-icon/) and the Rotated Icon might help solve your problem.